# calling same promise second time returning two response(first call and second call response)

Tags: javascript, promise

In the below code if the first request fails and the second request gives response the cp has both fail and success response in the promise. I need only the success response.

```
cp = getcp() // getcp returns promises
cp.catch(ex => {
  if (ex) {
    cp = getcp()
    cp.catch(ex => {
      cp = {}
    })
 } else {
    cp = {}
 }
})
```

I tried then, resolve but no use. Please help me in getting the success response only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't overwrite the promise object! `return` a new promise or value from the `then`/`catch` handlers.

Comment: @deceze can you pls tell me how to use new promise inside catch

Answer (score 0):

Your chain should look something like this:

```
getcp()
  .catch(ex => {
      if (ex) {
          return getcp();  // return new promise which may get caught
      } else {
          return {};  // return "success" value
      }
  })
  .catch(() => ({}))  // catch failure of second attempt
  .then(res => console.log('result is', res));  // use final result
```

You don't ever overwrite the promise object, instead you construct a chain of failure handlers and functions that return success values.

Comment: I tried this, still the cp gives the failure and success responses

Comment: There's no way this code gives *two* responses. There's only one `console.log` which receives exactly one value.

Comment: res gives only success response. cp gives both failure and success response

Comment: Wut? The promise returned from `getcp` both `resolve`s and `reject`s? That's something of an odd promise then.

Comment: Stab into the dark: you're actually invoking all of this code twice somehow.

Comment: yes I see both resolve and reject in cp. i am able to see both these statements getting executed .catch(() => ({console.log('fail')})) 
  .then(res => console.log('result is', res));

Comment: Well, yes, it'll first `catch` the failure, and `then` continue with the next success handler.